# Failed to install SQL Server 2008 Express/Developer edition on WIndows Vista Ultimate (SP1)

Tags: windows-vista, installation, sql-server-2008-express

I visited a few forums and tried everything short of wiping out and reinstalling OS while trying to install SQL Server 2008 Express; uninstalled failed installation everytime, cleaned up registry and install folder, disabled UAC, cleaned up WMI repository, rebooted whenever required etc..

Any solution will be greatly appriciated.

One of the links I followed...
http://mark.michaelis.net/Blog/SQLServer2008InstallNightmare.aspx

Looking at the excerpt from ../Logs/Detail.txt file below, not surprisingly Perfmon tool also crashes loading counters. Perfmon tool would work before install and after cleaning up the failed SQL install as well.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

2009-05-07 11:50:01 Slp: PerfCounter calling lodctr: 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Binn\perf-MSSQL$SQLEXPRESSsqlctr.ini'
2009-05-07 11:50:01 Slp: Prompting user if they want to retry this action due to the following failure:
2009-05-07 11:50:01 Slp: ----------------------------------------
2009-05-07 11:50:01 Slp: The following is an exception stack listing the exceptions in outermost to innermost order
2009-05-07 11:50:01 Slp: Inner exceptions are being indented
2009-05-07 11:50:01 Slp: 
2009-05-07 11:50:01 Slp: Exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.ScoException
2009-05-07 11:50:01 Slp:     Message: 
2009-05-07 11:50:01 Slp:         The system cannot find the file specified.
2009-05-07 11:50:01 Slp:
2009-05-07 11:50:01 Slp:     Data: 
2009-05-07 11:50:01 Slp:       WatsonData = perf-MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS-sqlctr10.0.1600.22.dll@OpenSQLPerformanceData@CollectSQLPerformanceData@CloseSQLPerformanceData
2009-05-07 11:50:01 Slp:       DisableRetry = true
2009-05-07 11:50:01 Slp:     Inner exception type: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
2009-05-07 11:50:01 Slp:         Message: 
2009-05-07 11:50:01 Slp:                 The system cannot find the file specified.
2009-05-07 11:50:01 Slp:
2009-05-07 11:50:01 Slp:         Stack: 
2009-05-07 11:50:01 Slp:                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.PerformanceCounter.LoadPerformanceCounter(String symbolInstallPath, String counterPrefixServiceName)
2009-05-07 11:50:01 Slp:                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.PerformanceCounter.RegisterPerformanceCounterCore(String libraryFileName, String openFunction, String collectionFunction, String closeFunction, String symbolInstallPath, String counterPrefixServiceName)
2009-05-07 11:50:01 Slp:                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.PerformanceCounter.RegisterPerformanceCounter(String libraryFileName, String openFunction, String collectionFunction, String closeFunction, String symbolInstallPath, String counterPrefixServiceName)
2009-05-07 11:50:01 Slp: ----------------------------------------
2009-05-07 12:02:40 Slp: User has chosen to cancel this action

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Answer (score 0):

Not much of an answer but I'd just bite the bullet and reinstall the OS.  At least you know it's going to work.